# Разбор стека потока

Tags: c, windows, kernel

Возникла такая задача: для некоторого потока известен адрес стека. Я знаю, что стек выглядят примерно следующим образом: [image: структура стека для потока]

И мне нужно узнать адрес функций А, B и так далее. Насколько сейчас понимаю, это определяется Frame Pointer - ом. Но голову уже сломал, как именно это реализовать. Прошу помощи, если это вообще реально.

Answer (score 1):

Картинка не вполне соответствует действительности. Frame Pointers тоже сохраняются на стеке (между `Parameters for function` и `Return address`) так что фреймы образуют связный список. Можно восстановить всю последовательность адресов возврата.

Имея отладочную информацию, вычислить функцию содержащую данный адрес довольно просто.

Не имея... можно попытаться найти инструкцию непосредственно перед адресом возврата (она обязана быть инструкцией вызова) и декодировать ее. Заранее предупреждаю, что это трудно и ненадежно, а если вызов был косвенным, то совсем беда.